# Login with Social Platforms (Facebook and google) doesn't work inside LinkedIn mobile app's internal browser in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic-framework, linkedin-api, capacitor

We are developing  mobile app using ionic and capacitor. Where we are posting a post on linkedin. user can click on that post and do registration . we are supporting multiple logins such as fb, google and apple and email.we are not able to login to fb and google in ios. we are getting 403  disallowed_useragent. Linkedin app opens its Default in app browser and  its not supporting other logins.[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkdDT.jpg)

Comment: For facebook Login via embedded browsers are deprecated. and i think this is the same issue with google but your need to confirm it.

Comment: my app needs to login with fb and google. linkedin ios app navigating to embedded browser. is their any alternative way to avoid this ?

Comment: you can use Deeplinks to open your application. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links

Comment: If it is my application i can use deeplinks to navigate . Now my scenario is clicking on link from linkedin ios app navigates to in app browser of linkedin. Herr no login works.We have login from fb and google and apple. How can i handle this scenario ?